# Multiple Consoles in one window

Tags: c#, console

I'm making a console application and ran into a problem. There are multiple console windows open at the same time and it's really painful to navigate through. Is it possible to create a "master window" - One window that servers as a base for multiple other windows?

Image explanation:
[image: Image example]

Comment: MDI style window ? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/795470/Creating-MDI-Forms-in-WinForms    and     https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C

Comment: Can you tell us the nature of those windows? Are the all generated from the same process? If so, what does that code look like?

Comment: Are you explicitly creating those consoles?  Some notes on your architecture used and/or some code would go a long way here...

Comment: Use windows Terminal as your default console, problem solved. However likely you need to rethink your problem and solution. The Console was never designed to be a complex rich interface, it was designed to be a console...